# Delete multiple rows in YII2

Tags: yii2

I have an array of objects fetched from database:

```
$masterListContacts = MasterListContacts::find()
                ->select('master_list_contacts.*')
                ->innerJoin('master_contacts', '`master_contacts`.`id` = `master_list_contacts`.`master_contact_id`')
                ->with('masterContact')
                ->where(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'slug' => $slug])
                ->all();
```

Under certain circumstances, I need to delete all rows from the database represented in this array. But with both *delete()* and *deleteAll()* methods I got an error `Call to a member function ... on array`. Could someone tell me please which one is the best way to accomplish this?

UPDATE:
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9c96/1) is my database structure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found better solution:

```
\Yii::$app
    ->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->delete('master_contacts', ['id' => $deletableMasterContacts])
    ->execute();
```

Where `$deletableMasterContacts` is array of master_contacts ids, which should be deleted

Comment: Probably better to use the function specified for this. [deleteAll()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#deleteAll()-detail)

Answer (score 11):

You can painlessly remove `->select('master_list_contacts.*')`.

```
->innerJoin('master_contacts', '`master_contacts`.`id` = `master_list_contacts`.`master_contact_id`')
```

performs the same work that `->joinWith('masterContact')`.

For delete entites try use this code:

```
MasterListContacts::deleteAll(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'slug' => $slug]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Onedev.Link, but it throws an error: `Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'` since I need to join table 'master_contacts' to do this......and just wondering does yii provide a way to do `foreach($masterListContacts as $record) $record->delete();` but querying database once.

Comment: Yeah. You can use `foreach($masterListContacts as $record) $record->delete();` code. `Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'` say that table `MasterListContacts::tableName()` does't have `user_id` field. What is your database structure? If you want delete records only with relation record in `master_contacts` you should use `leftJoin`.