# How to delete multiple rows in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have followed the link below in trying to achieve deleting multiple rows in Yii but so far the function I am using says it is not found by Yii, see the screenshot below.
[image]

This is the guide that I followed here in StackOverflow.
[Delete multiple rows in YII2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899009/delete-multiple-rows-in-yii2)

This is the code that I am working on.

```
$keyfordeletion = ActiveSubject::find($clientid);
$keyfordeletion->CreateCommand()->deleteAll('subjectcontainer', 'clientid= ' . $clientid)->execute();
```

What's happening here is that `keyfordeletion` will find all the values of `clientid` in the `activesubject` active record and will delete it through that function but it says the method is not found. So are there any ways to delete multiple rows in this case or solve the method function not found?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is static method `deleteAll()` for this in ActiveRecord.

```
ActiveSubject::deleteAll(['clientid' => $clientid]);
```

This will delete all rows from `ActiveSubject::tableName()` where `clientid` is $clientid. $clientid can be single value or array of values.

Comment: just a side note, this wont trigger the events in the model if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

you can delete one by one using foreach.

```
 $deleteall = ActiveSubject::where(['clientid'=>$clientid])->all();
    foreach($deleteall as $delete)
    {
        $delete->delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also a sql way to delete linked rows, with a foreign key and "on delete cascade" directive:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
  building_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  building_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(355) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (building_no)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE rooms (
  room_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  room_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  building_no int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (room_no),
  KEY building_no (building_no),
  CONSTRAINT rooms_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (building_no) 
  REFERENCES buildings (building_no) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

so if a row in "building" table is deleted, all related records from "rooms" table is deleted as well - without additional code.
for mysql this is only working with InnoDB engine.